# Using R for adding up value for each day

Tags: r, group-by

data_frame: counties

I'm trying to create a column that does a cumulative sum day by day for the number of cases like

Comment: use `group_by(date, state)`

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't add up the number of cases

Comment: perhaps you could add the totals you expect for each group?

Comment: Have you tried `cumsum`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to group by date because you want the cumsum to span multiple days. I assume you do want to group by state and county.

```
county_by_day <- counties %>%
  arrange(state, county, date) %>%
  group_by(state, county) %>%
  mutate(total = cumsum(cases))
```